# Java regex substring not followed by comma character

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string that I am using String.split(regex) to eventually get a string[].

The string format is

```
January,WEEKDAY,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,AJanuary,WEEKEND,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,BJanuary,HOLIDAY,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,C,C,CFebruary,WEEKDAY,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,AFebruary,WEEKEND,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,BFebruary,HOLIDAY,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,AMarch,WEEKDAY,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,C,C,C
```

The first string after the split should be

```
January,WEEKDAY,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A
```

So I'm thinking I need to do a split at either ,A or ,B or ,C that is not followed by a ,

To test the first one, I tried making my regex `"(?<!,)A,"` but that didn't work

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're looking for something like the following:

```
String[] parts = s.split("(?<=,[ABC](?!,))");
```

Or you can use a word/non-word boundary here as well:

```
String[] parts = s.split("(?<=\\b[ABC]\\B)");
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/zQlCxO)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `(?<=,[ABC])(?=[^,])` to split.